# PostgreSQL: performance of large inserts without index, temp table

Tags: postgresql, bulkinsert

I'm working with a table of 50+ million rows.

I'd like to know if I should expect a better performance if I first insert batches of ~50k rows in a temporary table, and then in one time insert all of them in the bulk table, instead of directly inserting the ~50k rows in the bulk table?

To be precise, which is better?

- Many small inserts into the target table
  or
- First insert into temp table, then all of them in the target table?

The table has no indices.

Any suggestions for performance increase are welcome, of course!

Comment: Insert all at once into the target table

Comment: direct insert = superior? @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: @Willem yes, it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `INSERT` performance should not depend on the size of the batch.

The important thing is that you don't run each `INSERT` in its own transaction.

Additionally, it hurts if each tiny little `INSERT` has to be parsed separately, so use a prepared statement.

If you do that, it should be faster to insert the data directly rather than using an intermediary table.